# I want to add a filter to android webrtc.For example, I want to give a Blur effect to the Video Frame

Tags: java, android, filter, webrtc, blur

While looking for an example of applying a filter to webrtc, I followed the part that transforms a VideoFrame.

```
   @Override
    public void onFrameCaptured(VideoFrame frame) {
        if (this.videoEffector.needToProcessFrame()) {
            VideoFrame.I420Buffer originalI420Buffer = frame.getBuffer().toI420();
            VideoFrame.I420Buffer effectedI420Buffer =
                    this.videoEffector.processByteBufferFrame(
                            originalI420Buffer, frame.getRotation(), frame.getTimestampNs());
            VideoFrame effectedVideoFrame = new VideoFrame(
                    effectedI420Buffer, frame.getRotation(), frame.getTimestampNs());
            originalI420Buffer.release();
            frame.release();
            this.originalObserver.onFrameCaptured(effectedVideoFrame);
        } else {
            this.originalObserver.onFrameCaptured(frame);
        }
    }
```

I succeeded in applying the blur filter using the onFrameCapturerd function.
However, GC is happening too much. So the camera works too slowly.
I went to a lot of places and found

```
ByteBuffer outRgbaBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
ByteBuffer dataYBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(strideY * height).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
ByteBuffer dataUBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(strideU * height).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
ByteBuffer dataVBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(strideV * height).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```

GC continues to run on this line. allocateDirect method How to solve it? 
Or could you please tell me another way to apply a filter to webrtc?

Comment: What exactly do you use here ?
processByteBufferFrame()

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Declaration outside the method, not within the method